# mg996r - maximum weight for robot arm

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, power, energy, electrical

I want to build a robot arm (see https://youtu.be/F0ZvF-FbCr0) to move a dumbbell of 2 kg (roughly 2.2 lbs).

However, since I have no background in engineering, I have no idea how to calculate / find out if the engines used (MG996r) have enough power to lift the object. How do I solve it? What is the conclusion?

If you come to the conclusion it has not enough power, can you recommend an Arduino-enabled engine that has sufficient power?

I am looking forward to your answer and thank you in advance. :)

Comment: To lift, one needs force.  Getting a large force from a weak motor is easy- just gear it.  Issue arises when you need force and speed.  How fast do you need to move it? 1cm/year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to determine if the robot arm can lift the object, you would need to determine the torque you need from the motor.
You should read up on how torque exactly works online. There is a lot of information online, here is a good start: https://theengineeringmindset.com/what-is-torque/
As explained by the website, gears could make a motor with less torque still able to lift the dumbbell, but this comes at the cost of speed.

Be careful when doing research though, there are also many bad websites explaining torque: If someone explains torque as "force/length" or "force per length" as opposed to "force * length" or "force times length", they have NO IDEA what they are talking about. (And you should find another website.) **The correct unit is N * m (or kg * m or lbs * ft) NOT N/m (or kg/m or lbs/ft).** Again, close the website if they're talking about N/m or something similar.

You're talking about power of the motor, but that is not necessarily what you're looking for here: power would determine how quickly the robot arm could lift the dumbbell, torque determines IF the motor could lift the dumbbell.

Comment: Wow this is very helpful! Thanks.
Just for a better understanding: How are power and torque related then? How would I calculate how long it would take to lift a certain object with a certain toque?

Comment: The unit power is often written in is N * m/s (force * speed). If you want to lift an object with a certain speed, you would need a certain force while simultaneously being able to achieve a certain speed.
It's not about the maximum speed you can achieve and the maximum force you can generate separately, it's about both simultaneously: force*speed.
This also explains why gears give you more torque, but not more power: you sacrifice speed for force, or vice-versa. If you were to use a very large gear ratio, you could lift a huge weight with a very small motor, but it would take a long time.